# How to store IP address in Html Form without functions?

Tags: php, html, forms, ip, ip-address

SO when i open this in google chrome i continue getting the following error:

This page contains the following errors:

error on line 60 at column 28: Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

But i see examples of tons of people getting the IP Addres this way. What Am I doing wrong?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE html
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>GradeYourTeacher.Com</title>
<style type="text/css">
p{
    color:black;
    f ont-size:14pt;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
}
h1 {
    color:purple;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:36pt;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>
<!--This Website is made by Francisco Sanchez-->
<!--Try to get IP Address echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  -->
<body>
<h1>Grade Your Teacher</h1>
<p>
<form id="myform" action="http://learncompsci.com/web/examples/forms/formReader.php" method="get">
To Grade Your Teacher Please Enter The Following Information:
<br/>
<br/>
Display Name: &nbsp; <input name="loginName" type="text" id="loginName" size="14" maxlength="32"/> (For others to view)
<br/>
Email: &nbsp; <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="20" maxlength="64"/>
<br/>
Email: &nbsp; <input name="password" type="password" id="password" size="14" maxlength="32"/>
<br/>
Confirm Password: &nbsp; <input name="passwordConfirm" type="password" id="passwordConfirm" size="10" maxlength="20" /><br />
First Name:: &nbsp; <input name="firstName" type="text" id="firstName" size="20" maxlength="40" /><br />
Grad Year:: &nbsp; <select name="gradYear" id="gradYear">
      <option value="08">2008</option>
      <option value="09">2009</option>
      <option value="10">2010</option>
      <option value="11">2011</option>
    </select><br />
Gender:: &nbsp; <input name="gender" type="radio" value="male" checked="checked" />
      male &nbsp; &nbsp; 
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />
      female<br />
Sports: &nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="track" />
      track &nbsp; &nbsp; 
      <input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="baseball" />
      baseball &nbsp; &nbsp; 
      <input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="lacrosse" />      
      lacrosse &nbsp; &nbsp; 
      <input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="paintball" />
paintball
<br />
    Banter: &nbsp; <textarea name="banter" cols="30" rows="5" id="banter"></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Enter" />
    <input type="hidden" id="IP" name="IP" value= "<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>" />

<br/>
</form>
</p>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you opening the file directly in chrome and not passing it through the PHP engine?

Comment: Yeah... I guess, I'm taking an intro to PHP class so we are reviewing html right now and i dont know anything about php, can you describe the process please?

Comment: Well all .php scripts needs tobe passed through the php processor, have you got a `WAMP` package installed?

Comment: As far as I know no...but then again I am not sure... is what I am trying to do way ahead of me? (I only know html and kinda javascript because i know java and c++, but i know they are quite different)

Comment: Ok perhaps, download a package like [XAMMP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) then develop your scripts within the htdocs folder, then test them via `http://localhost/yourscript.php` with web development its an ongoing learning experience. So I do suggest you constantly look up tutorials to learn from. Also head over to php.net its all there in great detail & also visit SO for help.

Comment: Alright thanks, I'll finish my actual assignment and not worry about this which i was trying to challenge myself to do. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the script/page parsed by the PHP engine, to have the PHP code working.

Or said in a simpler way; you need to put it on your webserver.

Usually, PHP beginners start out with a cheap hosting solution *or* - to save the expense - install WAMP, a simple installation package containing the essentials for parsing PHP locally - Apache (a webserver), MySQL (a database) and of course PHP to allow Apache to parse your scripts.

Try looking at either using some hosting or installing something locally.

Comment: If you're using some other OS like Mac or Linux, similar distributions known as MAMP and LAMP can be used.

Comment: for windows you can also use XAMPP (I prefer it) :D

Comment: Yeah i found that out in class today, thank you anyway, my problem has been fixed it works now :D